# Safety of reusing same seed to derive secp256k1 keys and AES-256-GCM

Tags: aes, aes-gcm, secp256k1

The use case here is to deterministically generate a multi-use wallet from a single 12-word BIP39 mnemonic.  Currently a standard process for deriving secp256k1 keypairs is implemented, e.g., using a derivation path like `m/44'/60'/0'/0/x` for an arbitrary x (0, 1...) to derive keypairs, which include a 32 byte/256 bit private key.  The use case came up where it would be convenient to also deterministically generate AES-GCM (also 256 bit) keys from this mnemonic.  I would like to reuse the same seed, with an as-of-yet unused derivation path (e.g., `m/44'/60'/0'/0/255`), to derive a private key that can be used in that way.  Are there security/collision/etc. risks that would occur from this approach?

Comment: Generally that is OK, but you haven't specified how the derivation path is used. Can you point out an algorithm or specification where that is defined?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Sorry - these are the BIP32/BIP44 style derivation paths like this: https://support.bifrostwallet.com/en/articles/5588263-derivation-paths-explained https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki